# My App crashes when launched on my Iphone

Tags: iphone, crash

I have a problem here : my app crashed on my Iphone (JB) though Xcode doesn't complain about anything. The app works fine on the simulator though.

However, there is this in the device logs :

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00078ac8 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00078ab8 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00078aaa raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0008d03a abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00044a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00005958 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00042df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00042e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00042f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00004838 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                 0x0009fd0e +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
11  CoreFoundation                 0x0009fd48 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  Foundation                     0x000125d8 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 64
13  Foundation                     0x000371e0 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 24
```

Any idea what the problem can be ?
I've already spent my whole day on that, but... I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance...

Miky Mike

Ok, Here is more then from the console, I get this :

> This GDB was configured as
>   "--host=i386-apple-darwin
>   --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys002 Loading program into
>   debugger… Program loaded. target
>   remote-mobile
>   /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-17280-65
>   Switching to remote-macosx protocol
>   mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache mem
>   0x40000000 0xffffffff none mem
>   0x00000000 0x0fff none run Running…
>   Error launching remote program: failed
>   to get the task for process 456. Error
>   launching remote program: failed to
>   get the task for process 456. The
>   program being debugged is not being
>   run. The program being debugged is not
>   being run.
>
> [Session started at 2010-12-23
>   20:33:33 +0100.] GNU gdb
>   6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1472) (Thu Aug  5 05:54:10 UTC
>   2010) Copyright 2004 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc. GDB is free software,
>   covered by the GNU General Public
>   License, and you are welcome to change
>   it and/or distribute copies of it
>   under certain conditions. Type "show
>   copying" to see the conditions. There
>   is absolutely no warranty for GDB. 
>   Type "show warranty" for details. This
>   GDB was configured as
>   "--host=i386-apple-darwin
>   --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys004 Loading program into
>   debugger… Program loaded. target
>   remote-mobile
>   /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-17280-72
>   Switching to remote-macosx protocol
>   mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache mem
>   0x40000000 0xffffffff none mem
>   0x00000000 0x0fff none run Running…
>   Error launching remote program: failed
>   to get the task for process 508. Error
>   launching remote program: failed to
>   get the task for process 508. The
>   program being debugged is not being
>   run. The program being debugged is not
>   being run.

Here is the code that calls the URL

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"TheLearningMachine.sqlite"]];

I hope this will better for you to read.

Comment: Probably the most unreadable post I've ever seen in my whole life.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to clean this up and ask this question again. I'm sorry about that but I still have problems with the comment edits and all the stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your app's startup code you're making a call to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`, and it's raising an exception. You need to check what string is being passed to it, perhaps with an `NSLog()` call.

(My wild guess is the value being passed to it is `nil`, because whatever code generates that path is failing for some reason. It's hard to say without seeing the actual code)

Comment: Ok, so the path is not nil, here is what I get from the NSLog when I run the simulator for NSLog(@"%@",modelURL);                                                 file://localhost/Users/Slim/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.1/Applications/949AB69A-3D13-4479-885E-EB6B0557081F/TheLearningMachine.app/TheLearningMachine.momd/

Comment: But what do you get when you run it on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Something in your code is calling `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` with a bad URL on the device. This URL is likely bad because you're referencing a hard-coded path on the device.

Check how you're constructing the URL - the simulator is more tolerant of issues here.

Are you trying to invoke something like mailto: or callto: ?

It could also be side-effects of a different problem, such as [this Japanese post](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/peccu/20101001/objc_alloc) that is calling init without having called alloc first - seems to have the same callstack as you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, thanks for your support and suggestions, Graham Parks was right. I've had a hard time though because I had no means of using the debugger with the Iphone. (Maybe because it's jailbroken). It's still not working by the way but at least, my app is now.

I don't know if you guys can remember the first time you saw your first app appearing on the screen of your Iphone... Waouh, I almost cried, all the more since I had just paid the 79 euros to Apple to find my app would not install on a JB Iphone.

This is my Christmas gift I guess.

As regards the bug here, the thing is I had mad a mistake in defining my URL.

NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TheLearningMachine" ofType:@"momd"];

The problem was "momd", (mom is much better) and is much more cooperative with my Iphone too ;-)

So thanks to all of you for helping.... And merry Christmas by the way !

Miky Mike

Answer (score 0):

Check your console. An uncaught exception was thrown; details of that exception will be printed out in Xcode's console.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, this line is the problem:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"TheLearningMachine.sqlite"]];
```

Try replacing it with this:

```
NSString *appDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSLog(@"appDirectory: %@",appDirectory);
NSString *finalPath = [appDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"TheLearningMachine.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"finalPath: %@",appDirectory);
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: finalPath];
NSLog(@"storeURL: %@",storeURL);
```

One of the lines above should produce a nil, or at least some kind of a strange value when it outputs it into the console.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, but I can't find any -(NSString*) applicationDocumentsDirectory method or property defined in iOS.  Are you defining this yourself, or am I being a doorknob?

Comment: Ok, guys, I've checked the console but there is something strange:                                                            Warning - No location found for "AddEntryViewController.m:70"
Warning - No location found for "AddEntryViewController.h:15"                                       AddEntryViewController is a viewcontroller which I have deleted but I used the find in project tool but it appears nowhere.... What am I missing ?

Comment: Stop the app, do a Clean, then Build & Run (or Debug).

Comment: Oh yeah, then answer my question about applicationDocumentsDirectory. :-)

Comment: // Returns the path to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}

Comment: It probably won't make any difference but, just for the sake of thoroughness, how about changing:  return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] to return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself and what I found that worked was to click on your file in the left hand pane to open it in the file inspector, then make sure your "Target Membership" (found on the right hand side of the Xcode Pane) has your main project checked. Without that your file path won't be correct and you'll get a crash.