# Simulator works; target device not!

Tags: iphone, gdb, ios-simulator, setup-deployment

I have an app that works on iPhone simulator but not on iPhone target device. I am using xcode 4.2 but my target device(iPhone) is 3.1.3. Never the less, I set the correct target platform but nothing happens. It just says 'Finished launshing app on device'. If I change my Scheme to 'Launch->'Wait for app to launch' then I get this error:

> There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-1004-70
>   Switching to remote-macosx protocol
>   mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
>   mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
>   mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none

This thread [My App crashes when launched on my Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521817/my-app-crashes-when-launched-on-my-iphone) has a similar problem but I don't get the rest of the error. only the stuff i posted above. I am using NSURL and I have a valid url and I am using a UIScrollView and 30 images with the total 'weigth' of 450KB. So what can I do?! Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to put armv6 in your list of Architectures under Build Settings for your project?

Comment: Hi Half_brick. Thans for the answer. Just tried that and it didn't work. Still the same error from above.

Comment: Note that there are about 6 places where you can put armv6.  It needs to be in the TARGET (not PROJECT) "Architectures", and the "Available Architectures" should include it.

Comment: @iPhoneNoob Pls Check the Architectures and Valid Architectures both should contain the armv6 and armv7 architectures. Then Build it, it would Build it Successfully

Comment: @HotLicks, half_brick and Marine Thank you both! You were right. I added armv6 to my architectures and it solved the problem!